# Cannot convert functional interface with generic method into lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Cannot convert functional interface with generic method into lambda expression.
Following code is working. It is without lambda expression i.e. using anonymous class.

```
public interface Pro{
    public <T> void callee(T t);
}

public void fun(Pro obj){}


public void implement() {
    fun(new Pro() {
        @Override
        public <Integer> void callee(Integer t){}
    });
}
```

I cannot understand how to use lambda expression instead of anonymous class.
After trying it myself I used the hint shown in netbeans. I used the shown bulb to do it.

[image]

And here is what I got, an ERROR.

```
public void implement() {
    fun((Integer t) -> {
    });
}
```

It is showing error. What is the correct lambda expression to be used here?
Here is the error :

```
one\LambdaScopeTest.java:18: error: incompatible types: invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression
    fun((Integer t) -> {
        ^
method <T>(T)void in interface Pro is generic
where T is a type-variable:
     T extends Object declared in method <T>callee(T)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get
full output
```

Comment: "It is showing error" is *never* enough information. What error, and where?

Comment: Funny how, IntellIJ IDEA does not suggest "Use lambda expression" but only the fact that with <Integer> you hide Integer class. Suggested the replacement only after i generalize the interface and not the method. Netbeans was wrong with recognize possible replacement with lambda

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is that you've got a generic *method* instead of a generic *interface*. That doesn't make a lot of sense. As soon as you make the interface generic instead, it works:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Pro<T> {
    void callee(T t);
}

public class Test {    
    public static <T> void fun(Pro<T> obj){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fun((Integer t) -> {});
    }
}
```

It makes much more sense for the interface to be generic, as then it makes sense to have different implementations for different types. For the *method* to be generic suggests that every implementation should be able to accept any value of any type, because the caller would be specifying it - which doesn't make sense if you then use a lambda expression with a specific type.

Your original version is only working because you're declaring a generic type parameter called `Integer`... you're *not* specifying an implementation for the `Integer` type. In other words, this:

```
fun(new Pro() {
    @Override
    public <Integer> void callee(Integer t){}
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
fun(new Pro() {
    @Override
    public <T> void callee(T t){}
});
```

... and I don't know of a way of representing *that* as a lambda expression. Basically, I think your original interface is inappropriate for lambda expressions.

Comment: I am sorry, but It is not my answer.

Comment: @afzalex: What do you mean? Without any more detail, I can't help you any further.

Comment: @afzalex: As far as I'm aware, you can't use a lambda expression with your interface in its current form. Your interface needs to change, and your existing code probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: You have completely changed my question. I know it can work this way. But why it is not working when I am making function to be generic, not class

Comment: @afzalex: I've shown you how to fix things, and explained why your original interface didn't make sense. Did you understand that the `Integer` in your original code *didn't* mean `java.lang.Integer`? I'm pretty sure the answer to your original question is "You can't." I was trying to be more helpful than that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59115/discussion-between-afzalex-and-jon-skeet).