# How can a concise closure be written for a generic method?

Tags: java, lambda, generic-method, generic-lambda

I want to write an implementation of a functional, non-generic interface which has a generic method. The implementation needs to be an inline closure and concise.

As a *simplified* example

```
@FunctionalInterface interface Fn {
    <R> R fn(R arg);
}
public class Scratch {
    Fn id = arg -> arg;
    //Fn nul = arg -> null;
    //Fn requiresNonNull = ...
}
```

which gives

```
/Scratch.java:5: error: incompatible types: invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression
    Fn id = arg -> arg;
            ^
    method <R>(R)R in interface Fn is generic
  where R is a type-variable:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>fn(R)
1 error
```

(In reality the parameter would be a generic interface with a methods that had a return type of `R`.)

**Is there a workaround without heading back to the verbosity of an anonymous inner class?**

There is an apparently similar question, "[Cannot convert functional interface with generic method into lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245448/cannot-convert-functional-interface-with-generic-method-into-lambda-expression)", but that stems from using a type parameter called `Integer` instead of something conventional like `T`, and Jon Skeet's accepted answer says he doesn't know a solution to my problem.

There is also a long discussion, "[Functional interface confusion](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/Functional-interface-confusion-td142863.html)", that fails to answer this question. It can't be "a verbose anonymous inner classes is best here", can it?

Comment: :P if Jon Skeet doesn’t know...

Answer (score 1):

Generic lambdas aren't legal, but generic method references are. You can cut down a bit on the verbosity of anonymous classes by creating helper methods instead:

```
public class Scratch {
    Fn id = Scratch::id;
    Fn nul = Scratch::nul;
    Fn requiresNotNull = Objects::requireNonNull;

    private static <R> R id(R arg) {
        return arg;
    }

    private static <R> R nul(R arg) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a solution from the cited discussion. There's a requirement for closure to be inline (and be a closure). It's just in the simple case that isn't evident. Perhaps I should add a more realistic but more complex example.

Comment: (Not my downvote, btw. I'm happy you've put effort into writing an answer for my question.)

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation and indirection I have a solution. I have been less successful with naming.

Here's the idea

- Neither the functional interface nor the single abstract method has a type parameter.
- The functional interface receives a consumer with a type parameter but that is wildcarded in the method parameter.
- The consumer is just a piece of internal gubbins, but it does have that type parameter. It is used to stash the result whilst execution returns through the enclosing function.
- The consumer itself receives a functional interface containing the actual business function instance which is of a type parameterised type.
- There's a default method that ties things together, including creating the consumer.

Clear? *[rhetorical]*

So instead of being able to write

```
Fn id = arg -> arg;
```

we can at least write

```
Fn id = q -> q.q(arg -> arg);
```

which is a lambda lambda factory.

We seem to have run out of syntax and can't write something like

```
Fn id = Fn.Consumer::q(arg -> arg); // not valid syntax!
```

Altogether (with a main to show I'm not cheating)

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

@FunctionalInterface interface Fn {
    interface Instance<R> {
        R fn(R arg);
    }
    interface Consumer<R> {
       void q(Instance<R> gn);
    }

    void consume(Consumer<?> consumer);

    default <R> R fn(R arg) {
        AtomicReference<R> result = new AtomicReference<>();
        this.consume((Instance<R> instance) -> { result.set(instance.fn(arg)); });
        return result.get();
    }
}

public interface Scratch {
    Fn id = q -> q.q(arg -> arg);
    Fn nul = q -> q.q(arg -> null);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String idStr = id.fn("cruel");
        String nulStr = nul.fn("cruel");

        System.err.println(idStr);
        System.err.println(nulStr);
    }
}
```

I don't *think* I've exploited any lack of soundness in the type system.

(I should probably add a more complicated example to the question to show why you might want to do this.)

Comment: Wow... my head hurts.